# Can I check in early, including my bags, when flying British Airways from Singapore?

Tags: singapore, british-airways, check-in, sin

I'm flying into Singapore on a low-cost carrier and have 7 hours until my next flight on British Airways.  **Can I check in early and leave my bags?** [The official website](http://www.changiairport.com/content/cag/en/flight/airlines.html) says:

> Check-in counter opening time: 3 hours to 1 hour (before departure)
>
> Early check-in timing: Up to 12hrs before departure (available between
>   0600hrs to 2359hrs)

Does this means I can only check in *more* than 12 hours before departure?

Comment: The time difference between departure and early check-in can be *up to* 12 hrs.

Comment: Gold medal for 10,000 views, and one upvote! This must be some kind of record.

Comment: Don't worry, it'll only get worse, that upvote was mine and that won't happen again as I am no longer on the site. Got here only because the notifications are cross Stackexchange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, you can check in early.  The confusing wording is attempting to say that early check-in opens 12 hours before the flight, so checking in and leaving your bags 7 hours before departure is perfectly fine.

Note that early check-in takes place at a dedicated "Early Check-In Lounge" behind Terminal 1, Row 5, a short distance from the regular BA check-in counters in Row 8, and this lounge lets you check in early for most oneworld airlines (and some others) in Changi.